# Unrecognized selector - Exception

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I have this Exception:

> 2016-11-27 16:37:28.416 Participact[8846:501284] *** NSForwarding:
>   warning: object 0x7ff90da33110 of class 'Participact.UserResult' does
>   not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector -[Participact.UserResult
>   replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Generated by:

```
let placesDataFinal = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.userResults)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(placesDataFinal, forKey: "places")
```

Where `UserResults` is this class:

```
class UserResult: JSONObject {
    lazy private(set) var taskId: Int? = self.deserializeJSON("TaskId")
    lazy private(set) var aggregato: Boolean? = self.deserializeJSON("Aggregato")
    lazy private(set) var tipo: String? = self.deserializeJSON("Tipo")
    lazy private(set) var valori: [String]? = self.deserializeJSON("Valori")
}
```

I think that for fix: inherit from `UserResult` by `NSObject`, but I cannot because it conflicts with JSONObject.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class UserResult has to implement the protocol NSCoding in order to be archived with NSKeyedArchiver.

See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html) on how to implement the protocol, basically you have to implement the methods:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```